# padding char array to a specific size matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, char, padding, pad

if I have char array,ex:  A='hello' of size 5 chars and I want to pad it with another character or set of characters to make its size =16 how can I pad this array in matlab ? and what should I use for padding can I use zero or I must use another character ?

Comment: Have you tried [pad](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pad.html)?

Comment: I'm using matlab R2014a ,it doesn't support creating strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
result = sprintf('%-16s','hello');
```

Or it can be created using array concatenation:

```
ex = 'hello';
result = [ex blanks(16-length(ex))];
```

Padding with other characters(e.g. 'a'):

```
ex = 'hello';
result = [ex repmat('a',1,16-length(ex))];
```

*As of MATLAB R2016b you can use [pad](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pad.html) function.

Comment: thank you , can I pad the array with other characters (e.g 'a') ? and how ?